# div table with fixed header

Tags: html, css, css-position, css-tables

I'm trying to implement a table using only divs while setting the header to a fixed position so we can scroll up and down and the header will always be visible.

The fake table was working pretty well until I started to implement the fixed header:

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/2wc5k450/)**

But when I set the `position: fixed` the size of the header or the body changes.

Comment: When you set it to `position: fixed;` you take it out of the flow of the page. The best way (or at least my preferable way that I've found) is to clone the table, and hide everything but the header on the clone using `visibility: hidden;`, and set that table to fixed position.

Comment: Also, you have to manually set the width of the fixed table. This might not be the best solution, but it's a start: https://jsfiddle.net/2wc5k450/15/

Comment: I don't want to force the web to have a fixed width or height, I want responsive design. :S

Comment: You should include the relevant parts of your code in your post. One day the JsFiddle link may rot.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [using position:sticky](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit), but this has [not very good browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky). Or, you could add a margin-bottom to the header that is exactly the height of the cells it contains.

Answer (score -3):

Try :

```
.table {
    display: table;
    width: 80%;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: I only want the header fixed, but the body has to be movable.